# How to put all css files in one file and all javascript files in one file

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, web

When I want to include any new `CSS` file or any new `JS` file, I put it in the header as this

## css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/header.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/index.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/footer.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/signup.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/contactUs.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/option.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/question.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>public/css/profile.css"  />
```

## js file

```
<script src=<?php echo URL . "public/Js/profile.js" ?>></script>
    <script src=<?php echo URL . "public/Js/cell.js" ?>></script>
    <script src=<?php echo URL . "public/Js/place.js" ?>></script>
    <script src=<?php echo URL . "public/Js/ontology.js" ?>></script>
    <script src=<?php echo URL . "public/Js/informativeObject.js" ?>></script>
    <script src=<?php echo URL . "public/Js/question.js" ?>></script>
```

I want something like

```
<header> 
include all css
include all js
</header>
```

Comment: How/where would you define "all css"?  At what stage do you want this to be expanded (given that the browser can't do that)?

Comment: in a folder called public/css and all js in this folder public/js

Comment: i am using MVC with .htaccess

Comment: i want to work on google chrome and if the answer doesn't work with IE  i don't care , i don't want my website to work with IE :) :)

Comment: use some tool like [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) for PHP, [webutilities](http://code.google.com/p/webutilities/) for Java or [Resources](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) for Grails...

Comment: i don't think you should avoid IE because most users are using IE. specially if this is your website you are using to find a job. IE is a pain but you will loose a lot of traffic if your site don't work in IE

Comment: for js you can append your path to html head with js. its easy

Comment: ok i know , but this website just for homework :) :) :) B-)

Comment: as that link i work this :
i put this on my html header
<link href="http://localhost/Mar7ba/public/css/cssFiles.css" type="text/css"/>
then in the cssfiles file i put thie
@import url('http://localhost/Mar7ba/public/css/footer/css');
is this right? cos it don't work

Answer (score 2):

[Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) is a PHP library that will combine all your CSS / JS files into one. Does that help at all?

Comment: it is forbidden on my country :(

Answer (score 2):

For CSS, you could use `@import`:

HTML with CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url('index.css');
@import url('footer.css');
</style>
```

Standalone CSS:

```
@import url('index.css');
@import url('footer.css');
```

Browsers include JavaScript as a `#include` AFAIK so there's no better way than including them all through `<script>` tags or by using Wintermute's example of a JS minifier.

Edit: [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) by Crockford is a CLI utility that you can use if you want to work with it offline.

Comment: i use that code in a css file or php file ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, the code example is for HTML which can be generated within a PHP file. You could also strip the `<style>` tags from it such that it would be pure CSS. In short, you could use it in both.

Comment: i understood from you this
1- in my html header i will put this 
<link href="mycssfile.css"/>
2-in mycssfile.css i will put ur code right?

Comment: I marked two code examples. In your HTML header, you have two options: 1) place the *HTML with CSS* directly into your HTML header or 2) put the *Standalone CSS* into `mycssfile.css` and include that into your HTML header as `<link href="mycssfile.css" />`. Either option depends on your preference.

Comment: yes man it works but i had to put this
rel="stylesheet"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got an array of files (using the local filesystem path)

```
print "<style type='text/css'>\n";
showall($css);
print "</style>";


function showall($filelist)
{
   foreach ($filelist as $fname) {
      print file_get_contents($fname) . "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: this code where should i use it ? and how can i call it from my html ?